# Getting error when using prepareStatement with interval in query

Tags: java, oracle, prepared-statement, intervals

When running this query `SELECT SYSDATE + INTERVAL '7' DAY FROM DUAL;`  in a `prepareStatement` like this

```
    PreparedStatement ps =  connection.prepareStatement("select sysdate + interval ? day from dual" );      
    ps.setString(1, "7");
    ps.executeQuery();
```

It will throw an exception, that the syntax is not good, it clearly is, cuz i'm able to run the same query in sql-developer.

Is this a bug in `PreparedStatement` ? can i use prepared statements together with interval?

Comment: Shouldn't "7" be set as a int value?

Comment: Try `interval '7 day'`

Comment: No, it should be a string, the oracle syntax for interval is `interval 'SOME_NUMBER' day`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The entire expression `INTERVAL '7' DAY` is a literal, you cannot simply replace a part of it with a variable (parameter). Use the function `NUMTODSINTERVAL(?,'DAY')` instead.

Answer (score 0):

PreparedStatement doesn't work with interval literals, so neither setInt nor setString works!
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm

For that reason if you want to dynamically change the days in your query (with interval literals), the only way is to concatenate that value.

In your example:

```
int yourDays = 7;
String query ="select sysdate + interval '" + yourDays + "' day from dual ";
```

Then you can use PreparedStatement if you need to add other parameters and to execute the query.

Answer (score 0):

It will work if you pass an int parameter multiplied by a fixed interval E.g.

```
select * from foo where (time + ? * INTERVAL '1' DAY) > current_timestamp
```

You can put days, hours whatever...
and than `setInt` parameter