# An arithmetic expression with a DATETIME value is invalid while using PreparedStatement with Arithmetic calculation in sql later

Tags: sql, jdbc, db2

I have the following sql query:

```
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PC_DATA
    WHERE PC_DATE BETWEEN ? AND (? + 4 MONTHS)
    AND UPPER(PC_TYPE) LIKE UPPER(?)
```

Now I trying to set the values of the `Dates` by the following code in **JAVA**:

```
Date start = new Date(quaterStart.getTimeInMillis());

stmt.setDate(1, start);
stmt.setDate(2, start);
stmt.setString(3, "%" + type + "%");
```

And when I run it I get the following exception: [DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-182, SQLSTATE=42816, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=4.16.53](http://www.sqlerror.de/db2_sql_error_-182_sqlstate_42816.html)

While I try to run this sql query from a console in the following way, it runs without any issues:

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PC_DATA
  WHERE PC_DATE BETWEEN  DATE('2015-01-01') AND (DATE('2015-01-01') + 4 MONTHS)
  AND UPPER(PC_TYPE) LIKE UPPER('%laptop%');
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: First, please [don't use `BETWEEN` with date/time/timestamps](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) (the blog is about SQL Server, but remember that you can specify fractional seconds in DB2).  What's the type of `start` - which `Date`, `java.util.Date` or `java.sql.Date`?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse - I must say that the points Aaron Bertrand makes in the post you linked to either are his pet peeves or inapplicable to DB2. There's nothing wrong with using `BETWEEN` with datetime data types.

Comment: @mustaccio . . . Aaron's points are very valid across all databases (in my opinion).  The issue is that when you *look* at code, you don't know whether a given variable is a `date` (with no time ocmponent) or a `datetime` (with a time component).  The meaning of `between` changes based on the underlying datatype -- a situation that readily leads to coding errors and maintenance problems.

Comment: @mustaccio - There's two parts to this for me: 1) The reason this is a problem in the first place is due to how numbers are represented in general (ie, this applies to all numeric representations save explicit integer counts), and 2) You [can specify fractional seconds for timestamp values](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0008474.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F2-10-2-3-0-6), which is _exactly_ the reason SQL Server has a problem (maybe not the iSeries version, but no matter).  I personally think `BETWEEN` should never be used for any datatype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A datetime arithmetic expression is atomic, that is, `<date> + 4 months` is a complete expression, so you cannot substitute just one part of it with a variable (parameter). You will have to calculate the upper boundary date in your Java code and change the query text to `...WHERE PC_DATE BETWEEN ? AND ?`.

See also [this somewhat related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29066015/getting-error-when-using-preparestatement-with-interval-in-query/29066241#29066241).

Comment: Thank you. Actually I've done this in that way but didn't think that it's only one possible solution.